# Error: Property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'ObjectBuilder'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need help with my Ionic typescript code.

This uses a Google Cloud Vision API to tag photos that you upload to Firebase Storage.

My problem: (returns the following error)

> error TS2339: Property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'ObjectBuilder'. 
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! functions@ build: 'tsc'

My ts file:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

import * as vision from '@google-cloud/vision';
const visionClient = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

//may need to delete, use default
const bucketName = 'outsidehax.appspot.com';

export const imageTagger = functions.storage
.bucket(bucketName)
.object()
.onChange( async event => {
    const object = event.data;
    const filePath = object.name;

    const imageUri = 'gs://'+bucketName+'/'+filePath;

    const docId = filePath.split('.jpg')[0];

    const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('photos').doc(docId);

    const results = await visionClient.labelDetection(imageUri);

    const labels = results[0].labelAnnotations.map(obj => obj.description);
    const sad = labels.includes('sad');

    return docRef.set({ sad, labels })

});
```

This index.ts file is located at AppName/functions/src/index.ts.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an old API that changed when the firebase-functions SDK reached 1.0.  [Please read about the changes here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#storage).  There is no longer an onChange event.  You should use one of the other events instead, and be sure to learn how it receives events.

There are other changes you should be aware of, such as initializing the admin SDK with no arguments:

```
admin.initializeApp()
```